# Spriting in CSS

Tags: css

I'm new to CSS and I'm trying out image spriting in CSS. I have an sprite map at present. There are multiple CSS files which are cascaded from my main CSS using @import. Each of these CSS files defines the layout for various components. I need only one call to be made to my sprite image hence I need to play around with background-position. 
Could anyone tell me a way such that I make only one call to my image and the rest of the CSS files just manipulate the position?

Answer (score 2):

You will need to work with multiple classes.

In the first class (lets call it `.sprite`) you have to define the background-image.

```
.sprite {
    background: transparent url(path/to/image) no-repeat 0 0;
    height: 16px;
    width: 16px; //assuming you are using this size for your icons...
}
```

Now you will have to define another class for every sprite image you will be using.

For example, you have an magnifier-icon, you will add a class `.sprite .magnifier` and there you will have to define your background-position.

```
.sprite.magnifier {
    background-position: 45px 30px;
}
```

Now in your HTML you just call for `<div class="sprite magnifier"></div>` and your image will just one time loaded.

Answer (score 1):

There are various [sprite generators](http://www.google.co.uk/search?rlz=1C1CHMZ_en-GBGB337GB337&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=css%20sprite%20generator). Or you can create your own using some kind of image manipulation software.

You'll want to save all the images in one layout as a .png (generally) with sufficient spacing between elements.

Then depending on your individual needs you *can* set the background of say all elements, to be your sprite, but this would potentially cause problems.

It's far better to say ~

```
ul.foo li {
    background:url(my-sprite.png);
}

ul.foo li.home {
    background-position:0 10px;
}
ul.foo li.about {
    background-position:10px 20px;
}
```

and style individual elements as required. The sprite will still be only loaded once.

You should not use sprites for lots of large images either - best suited for icons, buttons etc. See YouTube, Google, Stack Overflow for good examples.

Answer (score 0):

Give your elements the same class of sprite then override them:

```
.sprite { background: transparent url(../images/sprite.png) no-repeat top left; }

.add_icon { background-position: 20px 60px; }
.next_icon { background-position: 40px 60px; }

<div class="sprite add_icon"> etc.
```

and so on..